# G Suite Directory API: Fetch an access token from SAML bearer assertion

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-workspace

From the Google Doc, I see below are the options to fetch an access token for the directory API

- Web server applications i.e Client Credentials
- Installed applications (Mostly same as Client Credentials approach
  which we currently support but with the use of applications
  installed)
- Client-side (JavaScript) applications (For JavaScript applications
  that run in a browser)
- Applications on limited-input devices (For Limited-input devices such
  as TV, game consoles, video cameras, and printers)
- Service Account

Reference Doc:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

**Is there any API to Fetch an access token from SAML bearer assertion for the directory API and if yes then what information does this API needs and is there any Doc to do so**

Example Directory API for which I am looking to connect -
Directory API used for user creation: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at current Google doesn't support client authorization and authentication for their APIs via SAML 2.0 Profiles.*

#### More Information:

As you've already pointed out, the only supported methods of fetching an access token at the present time are those mentioned in the documentation page titled ["Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs"](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's Issue Tracker is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. While there is no component for general OAuth2 or Authentication methods, given your requirements I would suggest filing it under the Admin SDK component which you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102)

#### References:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs | Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

#### Further Reading:

- [RFC 7522 - Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0 Profile
  for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7522)